# opening multiple of boxes for an "interactive tutorial"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, interactive, box

it was kind of hard to explain this in the title but i want to do is make "an interactive" tutorial, where the user clicks on the area or product he wants to clean or to clean with, and then another box pops up with information, and when that part is done you continue with another box and so on... so i end up with like 7-8 boxes after another, and with like 30 products and 30 (områder)areas the way i am coding it will be very messy as i am coding it like "box1,box2" etc, just didn't get it to work with just one box reference in the css/javascript/jquery, i don't know if that is possible, or sort of an array could perhaps work?

What i am essentially doing is creating a new box with information on every click thus removing the other "main title" boxes.

You can check it out live here:
http://www.premiere-produkter.no/pp/metode/index.php

Javascript and html code:

> 

```js
$(".text2,text3,text4,text5,text6,text7,text8,text9,text10,text11,text12").hide(500);
$(".text22,text23,text24,text25,text26,text27,text28,text29,text210,text211,text212").hide(500);


$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.box').click (function(){
    $(".text").toggle(500);
 $(".text").animate({margin: "0px 4px"}, 500);
 //$( "div:not(:contains('box'))" ).toggle(500);
 $(".box1,.box2").hide(500);
  });
 
   $("#neste1").click (function()
  {
 $(".text2").animate({margin: "0px 4px"}, 500);
 $(".text2").show(500);
 
  });
  
  $("#neste2").click (function()
   { 
   
   $(".text3").show(500);
   $(".text3").animate({margin: "0px 4px"}, 500);
   
   });
  
  $("#neste3").click (function()
    { 
    $(".text4").show(500);
    $(".text4").animate({margin: "0px 4px"}, 500);
   
   });
 $("#neste4").click (function()
     { 
     $(".text5").show(500);
     $(".text5").animate({margin: "0px 4px"}, 500);
    
    });
    
  $("#neste5").click (function()
     { 
     $(".text6").show(500);
     $(".text6").animate({margin: "0px 4px"}, 500);
    
    });
     
       $("#neste6").click (function()
     { 
     $(".text7").show(500);
     $(".text7").animate({margin: "0px 4px"}, 500);
    
    });
    
    
      $("#neste7").click (function()
     { 
     $(".text8").show(500);
     $(".text8").animate({margin: "0px 4px"}, 500);
    
    });  
    
       $('.box2').click (function(){
    $(".text22").toggle(500);
 $(".text22").animate({margin: "0px 4px"}, 500);
 //$( "div:not(:contains('box'))" ).toggle(500);
 $(".box,.box1").hide(500);
  });
    
    
       $("#neste21").click (function()
  {
 $(".text22").animate({margin: "0px 4px"}, 500);
 $(".text22").show(500);
 
  });
  
  $("#neste22").click (function()
   { 
   
   $(".text23").show(500);
   $(".text23").animate({margin: "0px 4px"}, 500);
   
   });
  
  $("#neste23").click (function()
    { 
    $(".text24").show(500);
    $(".text24").animate({margin: "0px 4px"}, 500);
   
   });
 $("#neste24").click (function()
     { 
     $(".text25").show(500);
     $(".text25").animate({margin: "0px 4px"}, 500);
    
    });
    
  $("#neste25").click (function()
     { 
     $(".text26").show(500);
     $(".text26").animate({margin: "0px 4px"}, 500);
    
    });
     
       $("#neste26").click (function()
     { 
     $(".text27").show(500);
     $(".text27").animate({margin: "0px 4px"}, 500);
    
    });
    
    
      $("#neste27").click (function()
     { 
     $(".text28").show(500);
     $(".text28").animate({margin: "0px 4px"}, 500);
    
    });  
    
    
    
       $(".arbflat").click (function()
     { 
    
     $(".box2,.text11").show(500);
     $(".box,.text,.text2,.text3,.text4,.text5,.text6,.text7,.text8").hide(500);
    }); 
    
  
    $("#produkter").click(function(){
    $("#list").show(500);
 $("#list2").hide(500);
  });
  
      $("#omrader").click(function(){
    $("#list2").show(500);
 $("#list").hide(500);
  });
  
   $("#begge").click(function(){
    $("#list2").show(500);
 $("#list").show(500);
  });

});



<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function openPopUP() {
  window.open('http://www.premiere-produkter.no/datablad/11034.pdf','NewWin',
            'toolbar=no,status=no,width=600,height=800') }

function open11034() {
  window.open('http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=article&artno=11034','NewWin',
            'toolbar=no,status=no,width=800,height=800') }

function opensolchart11034() {
  window.open('img/solutionchart11034.pdf','NewWin',
            'toolbar=no,status=no,width=800,height=800') }
   
function opengummihansker() {
  window.open('http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&gid=5065&gidlevel=0','NewWin',
            'toolbar=no,status=no,width=800,height=800') }

function opengummihansker() {
  window.open('http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&gid=5063&gidlevel=0','NewWin',
            'toolbar=no,status=no,width=800,height=800') }


function openPopUP2() {
  window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Knf9YQeNVl4;autoplay=1','NewWin',
            'toolbar=no,status=no,width=550,height=550') }
   
function openflaske() {
  window.open('http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&requery=1&searchstr=b%C3%B8tte&searchfld=','NewWin',
            'toolbar=no,status=no,width=550,height=550') }

function openbøtte() {
  window.open('http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&gid=2214&gidlevel=0','NewWin',
            'toolbar=no,status=no,width=550,height=550') }
      
 function opendoseringbøtte() {
  window.open('http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&requery=1&searchstr=b%C3%B8tte%20dispenser&searchfld=','NewWin',
            'toolbar=no,status=no,width=550,height=550') }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<h4><img src="img/PremiereProdukter_logoSMALL.png"></h4>
<h5>Interaktive rengjøringsprosedyrer</h5>
  <h1 id="header"><!--searchbar--></h1>
  
<div id="buttons">
  <h3 id="produkter">Produkter</h3>
  <h3 id="omrader">Områder</h3>
  <h3 id="begge">Begge</h3>
</div>  
    <!--Produkter -->
  <ul id="list">
  <h3>PRODUKTER</h3>
  <li class="box" data-goto="default">
        
        <a href="#"><img src="img/11034.jpg"><h2>CaterClean</h2></a>
          </li>
        <div class="text">
        <h6> Produkt informasjon</h6>
       <p style="display:block; width:100%; background:#FFF; color:#000; font-weight:bold;"><b><a style="color:#000;" href="#" onclick="open11034();"> For mer informasjon om produktet trykk her</b></a></p>
             <p><button id="neste1">Fortsett</button></p>
         </div>  
            <div class="text2">
             <h6> Helse,miljø og sikkerhet:</h6>
             <p>Før vi går videre anbefaler vi deg å lese igjennom HMS datablad på dette produktet</p>
             <p>Punkt 4: Førstehjelpstiltak<br />
             Punkt 5: Brannsikrings tiltak<br />
             Punkt 7: Håndtering og lagring<br />
             Punkt 8: Personlig vernebeskyttelse</p>
             <p style="text-decoration:underline;"><a href="#" onclick="openPopUP();"> Last ned / se igjennom databladet her </a></p>    
             <p><button id="neste2">Fortsett</button></p>
             
            <!-- <p><button id="neste2">Desinfisering</button></p>  -->
             </div>
             
             <div class="text3">
            <h6>Arbeidstøy og verneutstyr:</h6>
             <p>Anbefalt verneutstyr ut i fra  HMS datablad:</p>
              <a style="text-align:right; text-decoration:underline;" href="http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&gid=5065&gidlevel=0">Gummihansker: </a><br />
            <a style="text-align:right; text-decoration:underline;" href="http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&gid=5063&gidlevel=0">Engangshansker:  </a><br />
            <a style="text-align:right; text-decoration:underline;" href="http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&requery=1&searchstr=vernebrille&searchfld=">Vernebriller:  </a> </p>
          <p><button id="neste3">Neste Boks</button></p> 
             
             </div>
             
             <div class="text4">
           <h6>Rengjøringsoppgave</h6>
             <p>Under velger du type renhold du skal utføre i henhold til området produktet skal brukes på.</p>
             Spray rengjøring: <b>1:50</b></a><br />
             Generell overflate rengjøring: <b>1:50</b></a><br />
             Frityr koker: <b>1:20</b></a><br />
             Mopping: <b>1:50</b></a><Br />
             Grovrengjøring: <b>1:10</b></a><BR />  
            
        <p><button id="neste4">Neste Boks</button></p> 
             
             </div> 
             
                  <div class="text5">
      <h6>Flaske eller bøtte </h6>
                <p> Velg hvilken flaske/bøtte du skal blande renholdsproduktet i:</p>
                <p style="text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer; text-align:left;"><a href="#" onclick="openflaske();">Flaske:</a><br />
              <a onclick="openbøtte();" href="#"> Bøtte: </a><br />
             <a onclick="opendoseringbøtte();" href="#"> Doseringspumper:  </a></p>
              
    <p><button id="neste5">Neste Boks</button></p> 
             
             </div> 
     
                     <div class="text6">
                    <h6>Dosering </h6>
                     <p>Hvordan dosere rett blandings forhold trykk på bilder under</p>
       
              <p style="text-decoration:underline;"><a href="#" onclick="opensolchart11034();"> <img src="img/doschart.jpg"> </a></p>
         
   <p><button id="neste6">Neste Boks</button></p> 
             </div> 
     
      
      
                        <div class="text7">
      <h6>Teknisk Informasjon</h6>
                <p> Her kan du laste ned teknisk informasjon om produktet:</p>
                <p>Caterclean 50: <a href="http://www.premiereproducts.co.uk/downloads/TIS/Caterclean%2050%20TIS.pdf" target="_blank"> Se her </a></p>
              
    <p><button id="neste7">Neste Boks</button></p> 
             
             </div> 
      
                       <div class="text8">
      <h6>Områder </h6>
                <p> Her er ulike områder som kan passe med dette produktet:</p>
                <p>Arbeidsflater: <a href="#"> <div class="arbflat"> Trykk her</div> </a></p>
              <p>Spisebord: <a href="http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&gid=2214&gidlevel=0"> Se her </a></p>
             <p>Kjøkken: <a href="http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&gid=2214&gidlevel=0"> Se her </a></p>
              
    <p><button id="neste8">Neste Boks</button></p> 
             
             </div> 
  
 </ul>

    <!--OMRÅDER-->
    
     <ul id="list2">
     <h3>OMRÅDER</h3>
  <li class="box2">
        
        <a href="#/australia/"><img src="img/flater.jpg"><h2>Arbeidsflater</h2></a>
        
          
         </div>  
            <div class="text22">
             <h6> Metoder for å rengjøre:</h6>
             <p>1. </p>
             <p>Punkt 4: Førstehjelpstiltak<br />
             Punkt 5: Brannsikrings tiltak<br />
             Punkt 7: Håndtering og lagring<br />
             Punkt 8: Personlig vernebeskyttelse</p>
             <p style="text2-decoration:underline;"><a href="#" onclick="openPopUP();"> Last ned / se igjennom databladet her </a></p>    
             <p><button id="neste22">Fortsett</button></p>
             
            <!-- <p><button id="neste22">Desinfisering</button></p>  -->
             </div>
             
             <div class="text23">
            <h6>Arbeidstøy og verneutstyr:</h6>
             <p>Anbefalt verneutstyr ut i fra  HMS datablad:</p>
             Gummihansker: <a style="text-align:right; text-decoration:underline;" href="http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&gid=5065&gidlevel=0"> Se her </a><br />
             Engangshansker: <a style="text-align:right; text-decoration:underline;" href="http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&gid=5063&gidlevel=0"> Se her </a><br />
             Vernebriller: <a style="text-align:right; text-decoration:underline;" href="http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&requery=1&searchstr=vernebrille&searchfld="> Se her </a> </p>
          <p><button id="neste23">Neste Boks</button></p> 
             
             </div>
             
             <div class="text24">
             <p><h6>Rengjøringsoppgave</h6></p>
             <p>Under velger du type renhold du skal utføre i henhold til området produktet skal brukes på.</p>
             Spray rengjøring: <b>1:50</b><br />
             Generell overflate rengjøring: <b>1:50</b><br />
             Frityr koker: <b>1:20</b><br />
             Mopping: <b>1:50</b><Br />
             Grovrengjøring: <b>1:10</b><BR />  
            
        <p><button id="neste24">Neste Boks</button></p> 
             
             </div> 
             
                  <div class="text25">
      <p><h6>Flaske eller bøtte </h6></p>
                <p> Velg hvilken flaske/bøtte du skal blande renholdsproduktet i:</p>
                <p>Flaske: <a style="text-align:right; text-decoration:underline;" href="http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&requery=1&searchstr=b%C3%B8tte&searchfld=" target="_blank"> Se her </a><br />
              Bøtte: <a style="text-align:right; text-decoration:underline;" href="http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&gid=2214&gidlevel=0"> Se her </a><br />
             Doseringspumper: <a style="text-align:right; text-decoration:underline;" href="http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&gid=2214&gidlevel=0"> Se her </a></p>
              
    <p><button id="neste25">Neste Boks</button></p> 
             
             </div> 
     
                     <div class="text26">
                     <p><h6>Dosering </h6></p>
                     <p>Hvordan dosere rett blandings forhold trykk på bilder under</p>
       
              <p style="text2-decoration:underline;"><a href="#" onclick="opensolchart11034();"> <img src="img/doschart.jpg"> </a></p>
         
   <p><button id="neste26">Neste Boks</button></p> 
             </div> 
     
      
        
                        <div class="text27">
      <p><h6>Teknisk Informasjon</h6></p>
                <p> Her kan du laste ned teknisk informasjon om produktet:</p>
                <p>Caterclean 50: <a style="text-align:right; text-decoration:underline;" href="http://www.premiereproducts.co.uk/downloads/TIS/Caterclean%2050%20TIS.pdf" target="_blank"> Se her </a></p>
              
    <p><button id="neste27">Neste Boks</button></p> 
             
             </div> 
      
                       <div class="text28">
      <p><h6>Områder </h6></p>
                <p> Her er ulike områder som kan passe med dette produktet:</p>
                <p>Arbeidsflater: <a style="text-align:right; text-decoration:underline;" href="#"> <div class="arbflat"> Trykk her</div> </a></p>
              <p>Spisebord: <a style="text-align:right; text-decoration:underline;" href="http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&gid=2214&gidlevel=0"> Se her </a></p>
             <p>Kjøkken: <a  href="http://www.premiere-produkter.no/main.aspx?page=articlelist&gid=2214&gidlevel=0"> Se her </a></p>
              
    <p><button id="neste28">Neste Boks</button></p> 
             
             </div> 
            </li>
 </ul>

    
</div>


</body>
```

Hope you guys understand what i try to achieve here, i'm not quite sure if i explained it well enough but the live site should be able to make you understand if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specifically mention all classes here to hide. You can use a class common to all elements say `.text-hidden` and in CSS add this code

```
.text-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Now that all boxes are hidden, you can have a function for the animation than repeating the animate code everytime, where you pass the element which needs to be animated. I have added a data attribute to each button called `data-next` which will have the box name to be shown when clicked.

HTML

```
 <button id="neste2" data-next="text3">Fortsett</button>
```

JS

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  var str = $(this).data('next');  // on click get the value from data-next of the clicked button
  animateBox($('.'+str))           // pass this value to the custom function
});

function animateBox(obj) {
   var $obj = obj;
   $obj.animate({
            margin: "0px 4px"
   }, 500);
   $obj.show(500);   
}
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/6b1hf3qa/)

Comment: oh wow that seems so simple, i will test that out and see if that works well! thanks! :)

Comment: well this solution does not work with the search filtering for some reason but other than that it worked fine! :)  finally had some time to work on it, so much other stuff going on at work that i had to push this back but now it is time to advance on this "interactive site" ^^